# Activator.CreateInstance() and Property Injection [Dependency] With unity is not resolving dependency and getting Null value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, unity-container

I am using Activator.CreateInstance(type) method to create object dynamically. For example

```
 public class Person
{
    [Dependency]
    public IStudent Student { get; set; }
    [Dependency]
    public ITeacher Teacher { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {

    }

    public void SendNotification()
    {
        if(Student != null)
        {
            Student.SentMessage("This is a Test Message");
        }
    }
}
```

When I am trying create an object using Activator.CreateInstance(type), Student and Teacher properties are Null. Using Unity with xml Configuration not fluent Api.

Any guidance to make it work?

Comment: I didn't think Unity dependency injection worked with the `Activator` class. You should need an instance of the Unity Container before dependency resolution will occur.

Comment: But Keeping reference to the Unity Container is not a good solution.

Comment: Create a global static singleton variable of your container. It's not worse than using the static Activator class.

Comment: As @GregBurghardt says I don't think Activator.CreateInstance would work with Unity. It seems strange that you would have to use Activator.CreateInstance(type) and I don't think having a reference to the container is a bad thing. Then you just use container.Resolve<T> resolve the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

As others mention in comments, using Activator.CreateInstance along with a container seems a bit strange.

But editorializing aside, you can invoke BuildUp which should inject the configured dependencies for you:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.LoadConfiguration();

Person p = (Person)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Person));
Person builtUpPerson = (Person)container.BuildUp<Person>(p);
```